# OpenCL, C - Leibniz Formula for Pi

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl, pi, approximation

I'm trying to get some experience with **OpenCL**, the environment is setup and I can create and execute kernels. I am currently trying to compute pi in parallel using the **Leibniz formula** but have been receiving some strange results.

The kernel is as follow:

```
__kernel void leibniz_cl(__global float *space, __global float *result, int chunk_size) 
{
    __local float pi[THREADS_PER_WORKGROUP];
    pi[get_local_id(0)] = 0.;

    for (int i = 0; i < chunk_size; i += THREADS_PER_WORKGROUP) {
        // `idx` is the work item's `i` in the grander scheme
        int idx = (get_group_id(0) * chunk_size) + get_local_id(0) + i;
        float idx_f = 1 / ((2 * (float) idx) + 1);

        // Make the fraction negative if needed
        if(idx & 1)
            idx_f = -idx_f;

        pi[get_local_id(0)] += idx_f;
    }

    // Reduction within workgroups (in `pi[]`)
    for(int groupsize = THREADS_PER_WORKGROUP / 2; groupsize > 0; groupsize >>= 1) { 
        if (get_local_id(0) < groupsize) 
            pi[get_local_id(0)] += pi[get_local_id(0) + groupsize];

        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }
```

If I end the function here and set `result` to `pi[get_local_id(0)]` for `!get_global_id(0)` (as in the reduction for the first group), printing `result` prints `-nan`.

Remainder of kernel:

```
    // Reduction amongst workgroups (into `space[]`)
    if(!get_local_id(0)) {
        space[get_group_id(0)] = pi[get_local_id(0)];

        for(int groupsize = get_num_groups(0) / 2; groupsize > 0; groupsize >>= 1) { 
            if(get_group_id(0) < groupsize)
                space[get_group_id(0)] += space[get_group_id(0) + groupsize];

            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }
    }

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if(get_global_id(0) == 0)
        *result = space[get_group_id(0)] * 4;
}
```

Returning `space[get_group_id(0)] * 4` returns either `-nan` or a very large number which clearly is not an approximation of pi.

I can't decide if it is an OpenCL concept I'm missing or a parallel execution one in general. Any help is appreciated.

**Links**

Reduction template: [OpenCL float sum reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613013/opencl-float-sum-reduction#20614016)

Leibniz Formula: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these are not most critical issues with the code but they can be the source of problem:

1. You definetly should use `barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);` before local reduction. This can be avoided if only you know that work group size is equal or smaller than number of threads in wavefront running same instruction in parallel - 64 for AMD GPUs, 32 for NVidia GPUs.
2. Global reduction must be done in multiple launches of kernel because `barrier()` works for work items of same work group only. Clear and 100% working way to insert a barrier into kernel is splittion it in two in the place where global barier is needed.

Comment: I completely blanked on the fact that the local barrier will have no effect on `space[]`. I'll split the function to get it working as you suggested, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also, having `barrier` inside a conditional like that won't work correctly. The rules for barrier are that every work item in a work group must hit it. With the conditional you have, they won't.